# In a Mule ESB flow, why is the output of a File to Byte Array node "unknown"

Tags: mule

I am trying to create a workflow that watches a folder for incoming files.  When a file comes in, I want to convert to a byte array for further processing downstream.

When I have no transformers, the output of the File node shows the Payload as an InputStream.

I then added a file:file-to-byte-array-transformer to the File node, but the output Payload still shows as InputStream.  Shouldn't it show as byte array now?

I then removed the transformer from the file node and added a "File To Byte Array" node instead.

Now, the output Payload of the File to Byte Array node shows up as "Unknown".

Isn't the output of the File to Byte Array node a known type?  Namely a "Byte Array"?  Why is it showing up as "Uknown"?

This of course is causing problems downstream, when I'm trying to use a data mapper, which then does not know the incoming type and therefore cannot map correctly.

Comment: Have you tried with a simple `object-to-byte-array` transformer?

Comment: Yes, I did try this with the same results, the output is "Unknown : Unknown"

Comment: Wait it's not the "output Payload" that is "Unknown", it's its detected type, right?

Comment: It is the output payload from the object-to-byte-array node that is "Unknown".

Comment: Wow, that's so weird. Show your XML config please.

Comment: I created a simple flow that uses a file starting node, an object to byte array node and a file end node:

<flow name="mule3Flow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="c:\input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:\output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>

when you bring this into Anypoint Studio, the type of the output payload from the object to byte array node is marked as "Unknown".

Comment: Ah the "type" is "Unknown" not the "output payload", as said in above comments. Yes, it makes sense, DataSense doesn't know the type after the `object-to-byte-array`. What type do you want it to be?

Comment: I would have thought that the type would be "byte array" or perhaps a POJO of byte array.  I'm not familiar with all possible types in Mule, but by definition, the output of an "object-to-byte-array" module should be a byte array.  Is there not type pre-defined for byte arrays?  Is there a way to set the type explicitly ?

Comment: The return type of `object-to-byte-array` is set to byte array: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/bfb3a17263d1e4b32ee10272cbf710a2bf41b16b/core/src/main/java/org/mule/transformer/simple/ObjectToByteArray.java#L31 All transformers have a `mimeType` attribute: if you had a specific mime-type in mind, you could use it to hint Mule about what these bytes represent.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key tricks to understanding transformers is to realize that they typically change the outbound `Content-Type` and *may* change the payload.  That is to say, transformers may simply change the way the payload is *understood* by Mule without necessarily actually changing the payload content.

Additionally, Mule seems to try to be 'lazy' in reading an inbound message payload (presumably to avoid loading huge amounts of content into memory at once), which is why it puts an `InputStream` into the payload of an inbound message.

In your case, I suspect that the `file:file-to-byte-array-transformer` is changing the content type that it *expects to read* from the `InputStream`, but leaving the `InputStream` as the payload.  As David Dossot suggests in his comment on your question, you might have better luck with the `object-to-byte-array` transformer.

Comment: I did try object-to-byte-array with the same results, the output payload of the node is of type "Unknown:Unknown".  I agree that Mule should be lazy about reading the payload, and postpone until it needs to, but the types in design mode should be clear.  A file-to-byte-array or object-to-byte-array node should have an output type of byte array.

Comment: The problem that this is causing me is that I then add a DataMapper node, which then does not recognize the input.  I can set the input manually, and I've tried to use "Pojo" with Byte or with Collection->Byte, but I cannot get the array passed to the next node.

The next node is a Web Service client which method takes a byte array (base 64 encoded) as an argument.  Trying all these combinations, I can get the call to the web service through, but the web service receives a byte array of zero length.